# TYPO3 Realurl fixedPostVars cache

Tags: typo3, realurl

Pages with RealURL fixedPostVars are not cached.

I have this configuration:

```
<pre><code>
'97' =>array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[cat]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table' => 'tt_news_cat',
            'id_field' => 'uid',
            'alias_field' => 'title',
            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                'strtolower' => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
</pre>
</code>
```

Is there any chance to cache pages like this?

Comment: Have you checked if there are noch USER_INT Objects on the page and no_cache isn't set? Also, I think cHashCache should be enabled in RealURL

Comment: I checked everything. 'enableCHashCache' => 1, no USER_INT objects. If I comment out this code, page is cached. If I move this code to postVarSets page is also cached.

Comment: Next try: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/36461